# I installed Arch Linux on a virtual machine with root password and without a normal user account , but I can't login

Tags: arch-linux

I am trying to install Arch Linux on VirtualBox by following instructions in some forums. I installed Arch Linux on a virtual machine with root password and without a normal user account, but I can't login.

I have set the root password, but skipped the user account,in mirror I have been told to do the country that is near me. In profile I did desktop Lxqt sddm.

I have reinstalled and did hyperland the same. I tried everything possible.

[image]

Comment: Logging in directly as `root` tends to be anti-pattern.  Have you tried setting up a user account?

Comment: Switching to a tty console or booting to single-user mode will allow you to log in as as root to set up a user account. You really don't want to have root as your customary login.

Comment: Why the closing of the previous question with the exact same screenshot?

Comment: I just tried to be clear in question.
and I forgot to edit.

Comment: i already tried that with setting up a user account.

Answer (score 0):

Most Display Managers (DMs like LightDM and SDDM) will not accept logging in as Root unless configured to accept it. I will not go into how to do this here as using Root for normal use (even inside of a VM) is strongly recommended against and is not meant to be used with most gui applications and can present multiple security issues

Furthermore most DMs won't be able to sign into accounts that have not been generated correctly with a home directory run the command in section 5 from [the Arch wiki page for users and groups](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Users_and_groups)

Furthermore you should follow the [Arch wiki installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide) instead of from "some forums" as the Wiki is updated while forums typically aren't

Also not to be judgmental, but but you also seem to lack some knowledge in Linux due to some lacking information in your question as in how you're "doing Hyperland" what "everything" is or providing a link to said forum post/comment. If this is the case I'd recommend dabbling in a less advanced distribution like Debian or a prebuilt Arch distro like Manjaro to familiarize yourself with Linux and/or Arch with less of the hassle of setup